# jQuery .change only works for first instance

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a series of conditional select elements that uses `.load` to insert dynamic content from an external file. The problem is it fires for the first element only and any subsequent instances result in no action.

I started off with this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {


$('#autocad-level-1').change(function() {

    var cat_id = $(this).val();
    console.log('Category Selected');
    $('#autocad-level-2-container').load('http://website.dev/wp-content/themes/dmi/ajax/autocad-level-2.php?cat_id='+cat_id);

});

$('#autocad-level-2').change(function() {

    var p_id = $(this).val();
    console.log('Product Selected');
    $('#autocad-level-3-container').load('http://website.dev/wp-content/themes/dmi/ajax/autocad-level-3.php?p_id='+p_id);

});

});
```

Research suggested I should use `.on` as the event handler, but I had no success with that either.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$('#autocad-level-1').on("change", "select", function() {

    var cat_id = $(this).val();
    console.log('Category Selected');
    $('#autocad-level-2-container').load('http://website.dev/wp-content/themes/dmi/ajax/autocad-level-2.php?cat_id='+cat_id);

});

$('#autocad-level-2').on("change", "select", function() {

    var p_id = $(this).val();
    console.log('Product Selected');
    $('#autocad-level-3-container').load('http://website.dev/wp-content/themes/dmi/ajax/autocad-level-3.php?p_id='+p_id);

});

});
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="autocad-level-1-container">
    <select id="autocad-level-1" name="autocad-level-1">
      <option value="0">Select</option>
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3">Option 3</option>
      <option value="4">Option 4</option>
      ...
    </select>
</div>
<div id="autocad-level-2-container"></div>
<div id="autocad-level-3-container"></div>
```

What am I doing wrong here? I'm out of ideas.

Comment: The second solution you tried should work... do you get any errors or console messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen to the select from a parent element, not the select itself.

```
$('#autocad-level-2-container').on("change", "#autocad-level-2", function() { 
    /*** code here ***/
});
```

Comment: They do... they just used the broader `"select"` instead of the `id`

Comment: Thank you sir. Problem solved.

Comment: So why does this work as opposed to using `'select'` as the selector?

Answer (score 1):

Try to delegate the events, if your .load changes the html of the page and replaces the original selectboxes, then the events that are bound to them get unbound.

If you try to do something like:

```
$(document).on("change", "#autocad-level-2", function() { ....
```

and the same for all the change events that you are binding on selectboxes.

Answer (score 0):

use `change` like below.

```
 $('#autocad-level-1').on('change',function() {

        var cat_id = $(this).val();
        console.log('Category Selected');
        $('#autocad-level-2-container').load('http://website.dev/wp-content/themes/dmi/ajax/autocad-level-2.php?cat_id='+cat_id);

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$('#autocad-level-2').on("change", "select", function()
```

to

```
$('#autocad-level-2').delegate("change", "select", function()
```

ALSO

```
$('#autocad-level-1').on("change", "select", function()
```

Change to:

```
$('#autocad-level-1').delegate("change", "select", function() {
```

Comment: Delegate has been deprecated as of `jQuery 3.0` http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: He had not speciied the jquery version he is using i he is using version 1.x  it works